# Do you need to create a web service to be able to support payments/donations via Apple Pay in a React Native app?

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments, applepay

I'm creating an app using React Native (using Expo, for what it's worth) and would like the app to be able to support donations via Apple Pay.

Expo's Stripe documentation includes a [Snack](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/stripe/#:%7E:text=First%2C%20connect%20to%20this%20Snack%20on%20your%20device.) that demonstrates how to support Apple Pay, and the documentation mentions that [the Snack uses a Glitch server](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/stripe/#:%7E:text=Under%20the%20hood%2C%20that%20example%20connects%20to%20this%20Glitch%20server%20code%2C%20so%20you%27ll%20need%20to%20open%20that%20page%20to%20spin%20up%20the%20server.).

Furthermore, the Stripe documentation also [seems to suggest](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet#:%7E:text=For%20security%20reasons%2C%20your%20app%20can%E2%80%99t%20create%20these%20objects.%20Instead%2C%20add%20an%20endpoint%20on%20your%20server) that I need to create a web service to make things work ("For security reasons, your app can’t create these objects. Instead, add an endpoint on your server that...").

I had assumed that Apple Pay took care of these sorts of things behind the scenes and that payments would be processed by Apple's own servers. Do I really need to create a web service to support donations via Apple Pay?

Comment: glitch allows you to fire up a nodejs app whilst the expo.dev site doesn't, you need serverside code to protect your keys, some people think/do it all done in clientside due to it being js all the way though https://glitch.com/edit/#!/expo-stripe-server-example, regardless the examples you see are not PCI compliant and wont pass apples guidelines they are just examples, is a bit unclear what you mean by *stand up*

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, thanks for the info! From your use of the word "whilst", I imagine you're not American; congratulations ;) From my experience in the States at least, "standing up a server" is used in a couple of different ways. It can refer to the setting up of the actual machine that will host one or more web services. It can also refer to the setting up of the web services that will be running on some server (which is how I meant it here). But now that I'm rereading my question, I realize that the way I've worded it could be confusing, so I'll change the wording a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, without doubt, you need a server for that. The payment intent is created with a secret key and your secret key needs to stay secret on your server.
Anything you put on the client is insecure and can be manipulated by those with bad intent.

If you wanted to have a client side only way to collect payments you can use Stripe Checkout, but from what I hear, it's fairly limited [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66573084/can-i-implement-stripe-checkout-in-react-without-my-own-backend-server)

Comment: Hmm, it seems like the app would need to store an API key, which the app would include with each call to the API (so that the API doesn't let just any old client to connect to it). So if the app needs to store an API key, how does storing the secret key on the backend improve security? Whether it's the API key or the secret key being stored on the client, it seems insecure either way. Am I missing something?

Comment: The simple answer is, the secret key gives you access to do a lot more than the api key does, and those with bad intent can scrape your key from the client side and then use it however they want. Storing the key on the backend restricts what can be done with it depending on how you structure your api because anyone with bad intent is limited in what they can do based on what endpoints you have.